# Traverse through directory of html files using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm setting up a simple portfolio site, which I want to load dynamically; I'm using  the jQuery plugin [pagify.js](http://cmpolis.github.com/Pagify/) for this. The setup of that plugin is quite simple, it's like this:

```
$('#page_holder').pagify({ 
    pages: ['home', 'about', 'contact'], 
    default: 'home'  
});
```

The only problem with this is that every single page you want to load has to be added manually to the array.

Is there a way to traverse through a directory, and add each page in it to the array? So if I had a directory /posts, containing the files foo.html and bar.html, it'd return 'foo', 'bar'.

EDIT: Should've added, the "backend system" (as far as you can call it that) is Jekyll, so it's just a bunch of html pages on the server.

Comment: What backend language are you using ? this is not possible with JavaScript as it runs in the browser and has no access to filesystems

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP as your server side language you can do this easily enough and add the results into your javascript:

```
$fileList = '';
$folder = 'posts';
$files = scandir($folder);
foreach ($files as $currentFile) {
    if (strpos($currentFile, '.html') !== FALSE) {
        $filename = str_ireplace('.html', '', $currentFile);
        $fileList .= (empty($fileList) ? '' : ', ') . "'$filename'";
    }
}
```

Now $fileLIst has your comma delimited list. Just use that in your JS:

```
$('#page_holder').pagify({ 
    pages: [<?= $fileList; ?>], 
    default: 'home'  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access directories or list files in folders with javascript.
This is for security reasons.

However it is possible to list files with a php, asp.net etc framework

---

To make things easier in the JavaScript you could have a array of pages in a json file that you could call in to each of your pages.

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
   $('#page_holder').pagify({ 
       pages: data, 
       default: 'home'  
   }); 
});
```

Json File:

```
['home', 'about', 'contact']
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build this JS using your backend code. here is a PHP example..

```
$arr = glob('slide_*.html'); //Get all files like 'slide_home.html'

//You'll need to get the array to a usable format to contain the terms 
//"home", "about", "contact", etc...    
//once its correct, and you have the default page in slot 0,
//echo the dynamic JS Code in the right place.

<?php
    echo "$('#page_holder').pagify({  ";
    echo "    pages: ['". implode("', '", $arr) ."'], ";
    echo "    default: '".$arr[0]."'  ";
    echo "});  ";
?>
```

Alternatively, you could just have your PHP page feed the array as @Blowsie mentioned below. The bottom line is you either need to manually add something somewhere, or you need to use a backend coding platform.